# Cannot find any WiFi networks on my HP Pavillion x360 using Ubuntu 22.10

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, network-manager

On a clean installation of Ubuntu 22.10 on my laptop with a intel WiFi 6 AX201 Wifi adapter, when I click on the Wifi icon, no Wifi networks show up. I've tried looking at other answers but they haven't helped me - I tried almost everything i could that is online. Please help (Ubuntu newbie).

**When I turn lshw -C network I get:**

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       logical name: wlo1
       version: 20
       serial: 50:2f:9b:49:4e:18
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.19.0-26-generic firmware=71.058653f6.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-71.u latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff irq:16 memory:600324c000-600324ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 18
       bus info: usb@3:2
       logical name: enx000ec6557297
       serial: 00:0e:c6:55:72:97
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 100Mbit/s
       capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=asix driverversion=22-Dec-2011 duplex=full firmware=ASIX AX88772 USB 2.0 Ethernet ip=192.168.1.166 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Then I ran iwconfig:
iwconfig

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

enx000ec6557297  no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=-2147483648 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on

**Then I ran:**
sudo rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Please help me I really wanna use Ubuntu but the no Wifi is really discouraging.

Comment: After a fresh boot, open a terminal and type `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network` then post the result please.

Comment: See below:
0000:00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:a0f0] (rev 20)
 DeviceName: WLAN
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX201 [8086:0264]
 Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
 Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
 Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
 Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
 Region 0: Memory at 600324c000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
 Capabilities: <access denied>
 Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

Comment: Hmm, search askubuntu for iwlwifi driver problems and you might get some ideas. It seems to clash with secureboot on some devices. Try looking for errors `dmesg | grep iwlwifi` or try updating your firmware `sudo apt-get install -y linux-firmware` and let us know.

Comment: Found a "solution": - Went ahead and purchased a WiFi USB from Amazon for $15, saved me the headache. Thanks everyone for trying to help, I appreciate this community!

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with AX 201, switching the kernel to 6.1-oem fixed it for me.

with default kernel (linux-image-5.19.0-32-generic)  `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` showed AX 201 being detected as AC 9560.